# getting id of last query when multiple queries are made

Tags: php, mysql

In php have a form with a textarea and a file upload. In mysql I have table 1 with rows for each uploaded file having data like name, size, etc... and I have table 2 with the data entered in the textarea and a column with the id of the file uploaded.

I'm using `mysql_insert_id` to get the id of the last inserted row in table 1 (the id of file uploaded). Then I insert that id in table 2.

Assuming that multiple uploads are made at the same by different users will `mysql_insert_id` return the proper id each time? What happens if 2 users upload at the exact time.. Or there is a timeout.. I guess I'm asking if there's a better way to insert a newly created id to 2 tables at the same time?

Comment: Ha, nobody jumped in to inform about the deprecated mysql_* functions.

Comment: haha yes, I was anticipating it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It returns the id of inserted row for the session from which the insert has been made. So yes, you're doing it just fine.

Answer (score 1):

Per the php docs ([mysqli::$insert_id](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php)) last_insert_id function returns the ID generated by a query on a table with a column having the `AUTO_INCREMENT` attribute. Thats for the specific resource you are using; other resources will not affect each other

Comment: also note I linked mysqli instead of mysql, I highly recommend using it instead ;)

Answer (score 1):

mysql can't give twice the same value if of course you have the auto-increment on the primary key of the table